# Deploying an Azure Function from VS Code - Succesfull but not visible in the Portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I created a function and I am trying to deploy it from VS Code by clicking the `Deploy to Function App...`. The Deployment runs successfully based on the output log - `Deployment successful` but then when I go to the portal, the function is not listed under Functions.

What shall I do and what is the problem here?

When I debug in VS Code, I get this: `No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).`

Comment: I can see the deployments under Deployments in VS Code in the Azure functions section but cannot really get it deployed as an actual function. I also noticed that you cannot delete function apps right now in Azure - it says "not found" for all my function apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I would not know if those steps don't work for uploading. The deployment finishes, and every single time it becomes visible in my portal. Uh, maybe there is a slight difference. The app service itself is pre-created via terraform. Just the uploading of the code I do via VSC.

As far as deletion goes:
Open the resource group, in the list lookup the App Service. Select the checkbox in front of it. Delete in the top nav bar of that pane.
Trying to delete it any other way will indeed give you the "Not found" error.

Comment: Marco - had to vote this down, this is a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same 'issue', in my case it turns out that the issue was a bad entry in the requirements.txt

I had an incorrect line with 'io' and when it was present despite the deployment appearing to complete successfully in VS code, the function was not updated if it was previously deployed or not deployed if it wasn't resulting in the same 'no results' in the functions list.

Having other requirements such as 'numpy' or 'scipy' worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but maybe it'll be helpful to whoever gets here in the future.

Even as of now, some changes I make in VS Code seem to take time to be immediately visible on the portal. I had a similar issue with resources, i.e. creating a resource from VS Code wouldn't make it immediately visible on Azure Portal. You can always go to `Functions` on the portal and click Refresh. Also try going to `Advanced Tools`, then `Kudu` and checking if your function can be found there.

One word of advice: if you publish your functions from VS Code, then work on that resource **only** from VS Code. You will find it reiterated all over Azure Functions docs that:

> [Publishing to an existing function app overwrites the content of that
> app in Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode#publish-the-project-to-azure)